# How to implement watcher to subdirectories?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm developing a cocoa application. As I'm new in this platform I need some help.

I implemented a directory watcher to root folder(Hot Folder). It's notifying me any changes made in that folder. But if I go in depth to that folder (Ex. Folder A contains Folder B that contains C.txt file) and I changed the file content of file C.txt it will not notify me.

What is best way to provide watcher to subdirectory? Is there any built in function which is used for this situation?

Project link :

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please provide a sample of the code you have used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SCEvents 0.1.1, it's very simple to use:

```
SCEvents *events = [SCEvents sharedPathWatcher];

[events setDelegate:self];

NSMutableArray *paths = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *excludePaths = [NSMutableArray array];

[paths addObject:NSHomeDirectory()];
[excludePaths addObject:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Downloads"]];

[events setExcludedPaths:excludePaths];
[events startWatchingPaths:paths];
```

This is a link to download it: [SCEvents](http://stuconnolly.com/projects/code/)

Hope this help.